# On a series involving harmonic numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

> Finding $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\bigg[\bigg(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\bigg)\bigg(\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{1}{r}\bigg)\bigg]$$

Try: Let $\displaystyle H_{n} =\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{1}{r},$ then series $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\cdot H_{n}=\frac{H_{1}}{2}-\frac{H_{2}}{3}+\frac{H_{3}}{4}\cdots\cdots$

could some help me to solve it, thanks