# Calculate $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1} H_n$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits

Define
$$
H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}
$$
I need to calculate the sum
$$
S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1} H_n
$$
Using the following integral representation of $ H_n$
$$
H_n = -n \int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln(1-x) dx
$$
and exchanging the order of summation, I obtained
$$
S = -\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}\right) \ln(1-x) dx
$$
Using Wolfram Alpha, I got
$$
S \approx 0.240227
$$
so I guess
$$
S = \frac{(\ln 2)^2}{2}
$$
But I don't know how to calculate the integral. Any idea?

Comment: try to use [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts)

Comment: It's $\displaystyle\frac12\ln^22$.

Comment: Can you expand on the step between the third and forth line?

Comment: @Pluviophile Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Duplicate of [On a series involving harmonic numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578657/on-a-series-involving-harmonic-numbers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integrate by parts
\begin{align}
S =& -\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}\right) \ln(1-x)\>dx\\
=& \int_0^1 d\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}-\ln2\right) \ln(1-x)
=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)-x \ln2}{x(1-x)}dx \\
=&\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx + \int_0^1 \frac{\ln\frac{1+x}2}{1-x}dx\\
\end{align}
and then substitute $x\to \frac{1-x}{1+x}$ in the second integral
\begin{align}
S=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}dx - \int_0^1 \frac{\ln({1+x})}{x(1+x)}dx
=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx=\frac12 \ln^22
\end{align}

Comment: +1. The integral after the IBP is also obtained directly using $$H_n=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\,dx$$ (not surprising since this also can be viewed as a result of IBP).

Comment: elegant integration

Answer (score 9):

My solution (sorry, didn't have time to write it up earlier) isn't that short, but rather straightforward: I use the integral representations $$H_n=\int^1_0\frac{1-t^n}{1-t}\,dt$$ and $$\frac1{n+1}=\int^1_0u^n\,du,$$ so we have
\begin{align}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\,H_{n}&=\int^1_0\int^1_0\sum^\infty_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{u^n-u^nt^n}{1-t}\,dt\,du\\&=\int^1_0\int^1_0\left(\frac{u}{1+u}-\frac{ut}{1+ut}\right)\frac1{1-t}\,dt\,du\\&=\int^1_0\int^1_0\frac{u}{(1+u)(1+ut)}\,dt\,du\\&=\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1+u)}{1+u}\,du=\frac12\,\ln^22\end{align}

Answer (score 6):

Summation by parts is a good way to go, generating functions another one. We have
$$ -\log(1-x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n}\tag{1} $$
$$ \frac{-\log(1-x)}{1-x} = \sum_{n\geq 1} H_n\,x^n\tag{2} $$
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n}{n+1}\,z^{n+1} = \int_{0}^{z}\frac{-\log(1-x)}{1-x}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\log^2(1-z)\tag{3}$$
and by applying $\lim_{z\to -1^+}$ to both sides of $(3)$ you may easily recover Professor Vector's claim in the comments.

Comment: Nice Jack , please explain me second line ,how can i get it, thanks

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n + 1} \over n + 1}\,H_{n} & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\,H_{n}\int_{0}^{1}t^{n}\,\dd t =
-\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}H_{n}\pars{-t}^{n}\,\dd t =
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + t} \over 1 + t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\left.{1 \over 2}\,\ln^{2}\pars{1 + t}\,\right\vert_{\ 0}^{1} =
\bbx{{1 \over 2}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**I thought it might be instructive to present a way forward the relies on using the series definition of $H_n$ and proceeding without using integrals.  To that end we proceed.**

---

The series of interest is given by $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}H_n$ where we define $H_n$ as $H_n =\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k$.  Inasmuch as $H_n=\log(n)+\gamma +O(1/n)$, the series converges.  Therefore we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}H_n&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{k(n+k)}\tag1\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{nk}-\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{n(n+k)}\right)\tag2 \\\\
&=\log^2(2)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{n(n+k)}\tag3
\end{align}$$

---

---

> **The interchange of the order of summation is straightforward to justify and is left to the reader to verify.  In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$ we used partial fraction expansion.**

---

---

Now, not that the series on the right-hand side of $(3)$ is identical to the series on the right-hand side of $(1)$ (indices interchanged).  Hence, we see that

$$2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{k(n+k)}=\log^2(2)$$

from which we find that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}H_n=\frac12\log^2(2)}$$

as was to be shown!  And we are done.

Comment: Nice solution. A real shortcut

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thank you!  Much appreciated.

Comment: Dear Mark, please point the OP to the other post where this answer is given instead of duplicating your efforts and the posts in the site. This helps us keep the site more-or-less organized and in turn helps users find your answers more easily. Thank you,

Comment: (I have now merged the duplicated posts and deleted one of the duplicated answers.)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Thanks for cleaning this up. Is it correct that – after the merge – this question is still marked as a duplicate of the other question which was merged into this one?

Comment: I suppose is it. Do you think this may be problematic?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff  I posted my solution to this page yesterday.  Shortly thereafter Martin R closed this question as a duplicate to an already posted question in 2017.  Since my solution was different in kind from all the other posted answers (yesterday's and 2017's), I posted my solution (modified slightly to conform to notation) to the question posted in 2017.  I didn't see this as an issue given that Martin closed yesterday's question.  For some unknown reason, this answer received two down votes, which I find curious since this be useful as yet another alternative.

Comment: @pluviophile Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I  really want to give you the best answer I can.